# how to describe each group after a kmeans?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I made a Kmeans algorithm and plot the result. Everything is going well but I want to know which individuals are in which group. is there a way (and what it is) to get individuals from a particular group?
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear.

> Here are the assumptions with respect to your questions,
>
> > 1. You want to get the label for the given data-point

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np

centers = [[1, 1], [-1, -1], [1, -1]]
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

km = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
km.fit(X)
```

Now def a function to extract the labels, using numpy

```
def ClusterIndices(clustNum, labels_array): #numpy 
    return np.where(labels_array == clustNum)[0]
```

Now for retrieving the labels using the same functions

```
ClusterIndices(1, km.labels_)
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
   17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
   34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49])
```

Get the datapoints

```
X[ClusterIndicesNumpy(1,km.labels_)]
array([[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2],
       [4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2],
       [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],
       [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2],
       [5. , 3.6, 1.4, 0.2],
       [5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4],
       [4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3],
       [5. , 3.4, 1.5, 0.2],
       [4.4, 2.9, 1.4, 0.2],
       [4.9, 3.1, 1.5, 0.1],...[4.8, 3. , 1.4, 0.3],
   [5.1, 3.8, 1.6, 0.2],
   [4.6, 3.2, 1.4, 0.2],
   [5.3, 3.7, 1.5, 0.2],
   [5. , 3.3, 1.4, 0.2]])
```

Comment: for example, I have a dataset of people and after kmeans I have groups. I want to know the people in a particular group

Comment: running the **get datapoints** will allow you to get a list of people in a group.Hope this answers your question

Comment: Is this what you were looking for@SidyMohamedAzizKone?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved the kind of similar task:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
colors = ["g", "r", "m", "c", "y", "k"]

for i in range(len(feature_coords)):
    plt.scatter(feature_coords[i][0], feature_coords[i][1], c=colors[kmeans.labels_[i]], s=10)

plt.title('Clusterization of the topics')
plt.show()
```

Comment: for example, I have a dataset of people and after kmeans I have groups. I want to know the people in a particular group

Comment: kmeans = KMeans(clusters_number, random_state=42).fit(people)
particular_group = 1
group = []

for i in range(len(people)):
    if kmeans.labels_[i] == particular_group:
         group.append(people[i])